# WKWebview: On click of button in app, play directly embedded Youtube Video

Tags: objective-c, wkwebview, youtube-iframe-api

I have a play button overlayed on an UIImageView (headerView) in my app. After the user clicks this button I want to display an embedded YoutubeVideo directly within the frame of this UIImageView. However, first my Youtube Video doesn't auto play and 2nd the size is way too small. What am I doing wrong? I have been googling all possible answers and tried everything. Or is it a simulator related issue? Here is my code which is triggered by the click of the play button:

```
NSString *videoIdentifier = @"EXaEz0mJXWY";

WKWebView *webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.headerView.bounds];
[webView.configuration setAllowsInlineMediaPlayback:YES];
[webView.configuration setMediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback:WKAudiovisualMediaTypeNone];
[self.headerView addSubview:webView];

NSString* embedHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
                       <html>\
                            <body style='margin:0px;padding:0px;'>\
                                <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api'></script>\
                                <script type='text/javascript'>\
                                    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() \
                                    {\
                                        ytplayer=new YT.Player('playerId',{events:{onReady:onPlayerReady}})\
                                    }\
                                    function onPlayerReady(a)\
                                    { \
                                        a.target.playVideo(); \
                                    }\
                                </script>\
                       <iframe id='playerId' type='text/html' width='%0.0f' height='%0.0f' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@?enablejsapi=1&rel=0&playsinline=1&autoplay=1' frameborder='0'>\
                            </body>\
                       </html>", webView.frame.size.width, webView.frame.size.height, videoIdentifier];

//NSLog(@"Embeddedhtml: %@", embedHTML);
[webView loadHTMLString:embedHTML baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my Youtube Video doesn't auto play

You have to initialize `WKWebView` with `configuration` parameter. Changing configuration afterwards has no effect.

```c
WKWebViewConfiguration* config = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
[config setAllowsInlineMediaPlayback:YES];
[config setMediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback:WKAudiovisualMediaTypeNone];
WKWebView *webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.headerView.bounds configuration:config];
```

> the size is way too small

`WKWebView` is using actual device pixels for measuring, and some heuristics for default scaling, whereas UIKit returns width and height in points. Simple fix would be to add [viewport meta](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) to the page:

```html
<head>
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
</head>
```